# RecyclerView Jumps in middle of the list when paginatining

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-paging

I have this page which I've setUp with MVVM and pagination using `RecyclerView` and Pull to refresh.
Clicking on some items in this `RecyclerView` will navigate to another fragment.

My problem is whenever I load the page for the first time and scroll all the way down in works perfectly. Pull to refresh will work as well.

But when I navigate to the other fragment and get back, scroll all the way top, swipe to refresh: The `RecyclerView` will jump to the middle of the page (Right on the item where I clicked to navigate to the other fragment)

**My Fragment**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>().apply { add(mainSection) }
        val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, adapter.spanCount)
        gridLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = adapter.spanSizeLookup
        with(recyclerView) {
            layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            addOnScrollListener(PaginationScrollListener {
                viewModel.onEndOfList()
            })
        }
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter


        pullToRefresh.apply {
            setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.window_level_2)
            )
            setColorSchemeColors(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.brand_primary))
            setOnRefreshListener { viewModel.onRefresh() }
        }
    }
```

**My ViewModel**

```
    fun onRefresh() {
        page = 0
        widgetItems.clear()
        _widgetListObservable.postValue(widgetItems)
        finishedLoading = false
        isFirstFetch = true
        getItems()
    }

private fun getItems() {
        isLoading = true
        dataSource.getPage(page)
            .subscribeOn(backgroundThread.getScheduler())
            .observeOn(mainThread.getScheduler())
            .flatMap {
                Flowable.fromIterable(it)
                    .toList()
                    .toFlowable()
            }
            .doAfterTerminate {
                isLoading = false
            }
            .subscribe(Consumer {
                finishedLoading = it.isEmpty()

                if (isFirstFetch && finishedLoading) {
                    _isMyPaymentsEmptyObservable.postValue(true)
                }
                widgetItems.addAll(it)
                _widgetListObservable.postValue(widgetItems)
                page++
                isFirstFetch = false
            }, {
              println(it)
            })
```

**EDIT**
when I remove the `onRefreshListener` on the `swipeToRefresh`in the first fragment it works. I have no idea why this happens?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Check if setHasFixedSize(false) works. Also in refresh part you can use:
scrollToPositionWithOffset (int position, int offset)
For recyclerview to get back at that p position.

Comment: Actually the problem was in onDestroyView, I didn't remove the pullToRefresh clickListener in the first fragment. when I did it worked correctly. I have pull to refresh in both pages tho.
any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding this two attribute to your parent layout of the activity.

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

RecyclerView might be storing the focusable to last item you have clicked or there are times when RecylerView autoscroll on data loading.

Comment: Yes, this did work out. `pullToRefresh.setOnClickListener(null)` worked as well

Comment: I did. Thanks ^_^

Comment: Tried no luck ,I think issue with pagination.

Comment: for me `new PagedList.Config.Builder().setPageSize(100).build();` works

Answer (score 0):

After trying `DataSource` `invalidate()` method no luck. so I changed page size to 100 and now its loading to 0 position

```
PagedList.Config config=new PagedList.Config.Builder().setPageSize(100).build();
    dataSourceFactory = inventoryTransactionDao.getAllInventoryTransactions(new SimpleSQLiteQuery(queryString, args.toArray()));
    LiveData<PagedList<TransactionHistory>> livePageList= new LivePagedListBuilder<>(dataSourceFactory,config).build();
```